Reversible vasectomy status
This question declares that vasectomies are forbidden, based on the Rambam.
However, unlike in the Rambam's days, vasectomies are reversible.
That being the case, then assuming such an act is still forbidden, and assuming there is an obligation to reverse the vasectomy (see this question), does the sin become a 'lav hanitak le'ase', a correctible sin, analagous to gezel (theft)?
A practical ramification to this question would be if the transgressor is liable for lashes, for example.

Although vasectomy is considered a permanent form of contraception, advances in microsurgery have improved the success of vasectomy reversal procedures. The procedures remain technically demanding and may not restore the pre-vasectomy condition.

Assuming it is fully reversible I don't know if it would be considered 'sirus'. Also, I think that there has to be an explicit 'asei' in the Torah for it to he classified as such. It's an interesting question, +1.

There are other irreversible side effects of vasectomy that may occur with man's reproductive system. In fact, they are commonly occurring among men who do not have relations over long period of time.

Is it still prohibited? Certainly yes. Rabbi Moshe Feinstein made that point about tubal ligations for women, by the way. The fact that it could be later reversed by surgery does not change that the procedure is "permanent", i.e. if left to nature.
You're asking if there would then be a mitzvah to go reverse it? Same as with lasering off a tattoo -- if there's no "thou shalt" in the Torah, there's no "thou shalt."
There could very well be an obligation to reverse it here, however, because of the general pru urvu obligation to have children.

if there's no "thou shalt" in the Torah, there's no "thou shalt." this tautology is likely a typo ?

@RabbiKaii, no. If there is no "thou shalt", then we can't come along and create one later. There is no "thou shalt undo castration" in the Torah; the prohibition is not nitak la'asei, and it remains that way.

This answer would be greatly improved by explaining the underlying kal v'homer that if tubal ligation is assur for women,then all the more so a vasectomy for men and why

This is a good answer. Could you provide the exact source in Igrot Moshe?

@ יהושע ק  because all of the examples given in the Chumash are about males rather than females?
